# GE smart switch neutral power requirement

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, home-automation

How many neutral watts are required for most smart switches? I'm unable to get any juice from unit even though there is a neutral wire. I.e. [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0035YRCR2/ref=pd_aw_lpo_60_bs_img_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=D0MQ8RV3FMBAGS4GNRE1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0035YRCR2)

[image]

Comment: Is the wire neutral, or merely white?

Comment: What is your picture intended to show us? I don't see any neutrals connected - they're all nutted together at the back of the box.

Comment: Well if they're all nutted together they are assuredly neutrals.  We don't measure current flow to wires in watts, but any smart switch will be at less than 1 watt, which will amount to a few milliamps of flow, a trivial amount.

Comment: @Harper ... Good point, line has a reading on a multimeter, so I assumed it was neutral, and three other outlets in home have a white cord that power a similar GE switch. Guess my next query is how to determine a neutral line.

Comment: Well to start a neutral should never have wattage so to speak. It should read 0 to ground and normal voltage to any hot wire.

Comment: @Harper they're definitely nutted together, unfortunately the switch isn't turning on, tested outlet with another smart switch and it doesn't power unit. Will test unit on an outlet with a neutral that I know works. It seems the blue light on the switch will turn on if neutral is connected accurately, perhaps the issue is something else in the connection such as the cord, which likely isn't the issue since anther similar unit works with the same cord, or the units don't work.

Answer (score 1):

There was should have been a little Grey wire that came with your switch.

The NEUTRALS that are tucked away in the back of that receptacle need to have that grey wire attached - so undo the wire nut that has the whites all together and add the grey wire - place the wire nut back on.

Connect the Grey wire to the neutral connection on your new switch. 
That connection is probably located in the Lower Right corner across from the Line connection and has the writing Neutral on it - there is a brass screw on the side but also there are two holes on the back side to insert two wires.

[image: Z-Wave Switch]